# kube-dns cannot find api-server

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I´m setting up kubernetes on GKE as described in Kelsey Hightowers https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/

Everything works fine except for setting up the DNS ClusterAddon https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/12-dns-addon.md

When I start kube-dns like that:

> kubectl create -f
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-the-hard-way/kube-dns.yaml

I do get the expected output :

```
 serviceaccount "kube-dns" created 
 configmap "kube-dns" created 
 service "kube-dns" 
 created deployment "kube-dns" created
```

But checking state of the pods and the output of the kube-dns container I see errors:

```
kubectl get po -n kube-system
NAME                        READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-dns-6c857864fb-cpvvr   2/3       CrashLoopBackOff   63         2h
```

and in the container log:

```
I0115 13:22:35.272492       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0115 13:22:35.772476       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0115 13:22:36.272406       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0115 13:22:36.772356       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
I0115 13:22:37.272386       1 dns.go:173] Waiting for services and endpoints to be initialized from apiserver...
E0115 13:22:37.273178       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/dns/pkg/dns/dns.go:147: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.32.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.32.0.1:443: i/o timeout
E0115 13:22:37.273340       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/dns/pkg/dns/dns.go:150: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.32.0.1:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.32.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

The URL https://10.32.0.1:443 in the container log seems to be wrong, but I cannot find any place where I can specify a different URL and neither the place where this URL is set in the config file https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-the-hard-way/kube-dns.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL comes from internal kubernetes information (service account token) and it should be fine (it should point to the first IP in the range assigned to service network, and that should be the `kubernetes.default` service. What you need to check is if your pod-to-pod networking and kube-proxy (it implements service ClusterIPs) works as expected.

If you do `kubectl get svc kubernetes -o yaml` you should see a kubernetes service with that `10.32.0.1` IP so confirm that as well (apiserver registers its own IP for this svc so doing `ksp get endpoints kubernetes` should give you API IP/PORT)

Comment: Thanks, kubectl get svc kubernetes -o yaml shows just what you expected.
pod-to-pod networking works find (i can ping pod from different nodes.
checking the kube-proxy next

Comment: kube-proxy has aut. issues: 
Jan 15 22:05:48 worker-2 kube-proxy[2920]: E0115 22:05:48.880162    2920 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/informers/informers_generated/internalversion/factory.go:85: Failed to list *core.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list endpoints at the cluster scope

Comment: i checked my kubeconfig file and the user section was empty. as you told.
my bad. thanks!

Comment: @christian which file exactly and what section did you correct to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was using kubespray (release v2.5.0) to try to setup a kubernetes (version 1.10.4) cluster on Openstack and got problem with exactly same error messages. Google led me here but didn't provide a solution for this problem.

My final solution is change kube_proxy_mode option in inventory/mycluster/group_vars/kube-cluster.yml, from default value of 'iptables' to 'ipvs':

```
# Kube-proxy proxyMode configuration.
# Can be ipvs, iptables
kube_proxy_mode: ipvs
```

After that re-run the ansible playbook command, then this issue is gone and all services/pods are running as expected. Hope it's helpful for those who try with the same toolchain to setup a kubernetes cluster.

Comment: did you happen to use calico?